# trying to convert my video using laravel ffmpeg

Tags: laravel

I am trying to convert my video using laravel ffmpeg but I am getting error message saying

> "Unable to probe 5bb990e27207cislands2.mp4"

I don't know why is that. Did I successfully download it? Can someone help me please?

**Here is my code**

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$pro = User::find($user_id);
$pro->nickname=$request->nickname;

if($request->video) {
    $vid = $request->file('video');
    $filename = uniqid().$vid->getClientOriginalName();
    $vid = $request->file('video');
    // $filename = uniqid().$vid->getClientOriginalName();
    // $path = $vid->storeAs('introvideo', $filename);

    $ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
        'ffmpeg.binaries'  => "C:/Users/Riche/Desktop/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe",
        'ffprobe.binaries' => "C:/Users/Riche/Desktop/ffmpeg/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe"
    ]);

    $video = $ffmpeg->open($filename)->export()
        ->toDisk('s3')
        ->inFormat(new \FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264)
        ->save('myvideo.mp4');

    $t = Storage::disk('s3')->put($filename, file_get_contents($vid), 'public');
    $imageName = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);
    // $vid->move($location);
    $pro->intro_video = $video;

}

$pro->save();
```

Comment: please, tell us the version and the path of your ffmpeg.

Comment: did you set up the environment variable FFMPEG in .env?

Comment: @staskrak I downloaded the latest version from here https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg and the path for the binaries I showed that in my code if you take one more look. Also which env are you referring to if I may ask?

Comment: Try to print the $filename variable before calling the $ffmpeg->open() method and check if the file exists in that location.